# Checking the data being received on server end of android application

Tags: php, android, android-volley

Is there any method to check the data/query that is being received on the server side of a android application?
I'm using Volley to make a query in my database, sending username to access the profile. I'm not sure what "username" is being sent to server.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                Log.d(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext()),"Response generated");                }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.d("Error - >",error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error is -->> " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                SharedPreferences sp;
                sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                String userid = sp.getString("userid", "");
                params.put("userid", userid);
                return params;
            }};
```

Here is the Php script to get the userid

```
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
//$userid = "deejay";
```

if I use $userid= "deejay" the response is generated. so I'm sure the error is with my POST method but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you better explain what it is that you are trying to ask? Your question isn't entirely understandable.

Comment: @Knossos, Okay, I'm using Volley Request to send a userid from my android application to server, now using this userid (in my php script on server) i want to fetch the username, email and other data from my database and send it back in response to my application. If i use a hard coded userid e.g. '$userid = "deejay";' in my php script for query, i can get the response but if i try to use a variable like '$userid = $_POST['userid'];' i can't see anything.
Now i want to make sure that if anything is being passed to server in userid or not.. is it possible to see whats going on in script?

Comment: Firstly, edit your question with the additional information. It will confuse other possible answerers otherwise. Secondly, you will need to post your code for the server and client (or at least the applicable parts of it). Thirdly, using only the userid to authenticate with a server is a gigantic security problem. I would recommend you do some serious reading into authenticating with a server before you go ahead with that course of action.

Comment: @Knossos thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into that authenticating case later, but for right now the security isn't my main concern.
Please check the question I've added my code.

Comment: Is the variable `userid` = "" in this case? Log it: `String userid = sp.getString("userid", "");`. In the PHP you should echo out `$userid` so that your Java can see what the PHP receives.

Comment: I'm using the userid from my previous activity using SharedPreferences. and I'm using Toast to make sure the userid isn't empty.
Is it what you are asking to try? echo "Current User is :: ".$userid;